# How to find the Purchase state in the new Sell Subscriptions API?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

When [integrating the Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate), how to know the state of a subscription? I want to know what of the below states is it, base on the [Sell Subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs) lifecycle.

- Active
- Cancelled
- In grace period
- On hold
- Paused
- Expired

To be more precise, when registering to `PurchasesUpdatedListener` via `BillingClient.newBuilder(activity).setListener()` you are getting a list of purchases via `onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult, List<Purchase>)`, how to know the state of each subscription purchase based on the above states?

At the moment I extract the purchase time from `purchase.getPurchaseTime()` and the subscription period from `skuDetails.getSubscriptionPeriod()` to check if the subscription is active. But that only gives me the Expired and the Active states, how can I get the rest?

Also, I am aware of the [Real-time developer notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn), but I want to handle this, solely on the client.

Comment: Hello! Have you found any solution?